# Elasticsearch term suggester does not return results on exact match

Tags: elasticsearch, search-suggestion

when i request the suggester with

```
{
    "my-title-suggestions-1": {
       "text": "tücher                ",
       "term": {
            "field": "name",
       }
    },
    "my-title-suggestions-2": {
       "text": "tüchers                ",
       "term": {
           "field": "name"
       }
    }
}
```

it returns

```
{
    "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
    },
    "my-title-suggestions-1": [
    {
        "text": "tücher",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 6,
        "options": []
    }
    ],
    "my-title-suggestions-2": [
    {
        "text": "tüchers",
        "offset": 0,
        "length": 7,
        "options": [
            {
                "text": "tücher",
                "score": 0.8333333,
                "freq": 6
            }
        ]
    }
    ]
}
```

i wonder why it does not return the exact match with the first suggester? 
the second suggester obviously has that result.

can i add other options which will resolve this behavior?

edit: 
the minimal mapping is just this ...

```
{
"name" : {
        "analyzer" : "standard",
        "type" : "string"
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post the index mapping too?

Comment: @madsen the specific structure of the mapping should be irrelevant ... it has a string field  named name ... however i added the mapping

Comment: It's not necessarily irrelevant if the field is analyzed, filtered and/or tokenized.

Comment: I currently have the same problem. Here is the the relevant [issue](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/11579) and [pull request](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/15410). Currently open but seems ready for merge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add to what @ChintanShah25 said: According to https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/search-suggesters-term.html (see `suggest_mode`) the Term suggester will by default:

> Only provide suggestions for suggest text terms that are not in the index.

Comment: It doesn't seem like even using `always` causes an exact match to come back, at least not in es1.5

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you can do that and I am not sure why do you want exact match in `suggestions`, after all they are "suggestions".

Normally they are used to check misspelling. It will give you candidate suggestions that are similar and fall in `edit distance` of 2 for the word you entered.

Comment: yes, im currently poisoning the request with an additional character and this "works for me" for now ...